# Syntax error in Ansible playbook using dictionary and loop

Tags: ansible, yaml

I have the following dictionary in my vars/ directory.

vars_dict.yml

```
---
ruleset:
  rule1:
    rule_name: testrule1
    description: Test Rule number 1
    source_zone: trust
    destination_zone: untrust
    source_ip: 1.2.3.4
    source_user: any
    destination_ip: 4.5.6.7
    action: allow
    disabled: FALSE
    location: top
    log_end: TRUE
    tag_name: superimportant
    vsys: vsys1
    state: present
    commit: TRUE
  rule2:
    rule_name: testrule2
    description: Test Rule number 2
    source_zone: trust
    destination_zone: untrust
    source_ip: 1.2.3.5
    source_user: any
    destination_ip: 4.5.6.8
    action: allow
    disabled: FALSE
    location: bottom
    log_end: TRUE
    tag_name: superimportant
    vsys: vsys1
    state: present
    commit: TRUE
...
```

I also have these supporting variable files in vars/:

credentials.yml

```
fw_username: test
fw_password: test
```

and fw.yml

```
fw_ip_address: 192.168.1.1
```

I would like to loop through each set of data to send commands to a firewall using this playbook:

```
---
- hosts: localhost
  connection: local

  roles:
    - role: PaloAltoNetworks.paloaltonetworks

  tasks:
    - name: include variables
      include_vars:
        dir: vars

    - name: Add superimportant rules to the firewall
      panos_security_rule:
        ip_address: '{{ fw_ip_address }}'
        username: '{{ fw_username }}'
        password: '{{ fw_password }}'
        rule_name: '{{ ruleset.rule_name }}'
        description: '{{ ruleset.description }}'
        source_zone: ['{{ ruleset.source_zone }}']
        destination_zone: ['{{ ruleset.destination_zone }}']
        source_ip: ['{{ ruleset.source_ip }}']
        source_user: ['{{ ruleset.source_user }}']
        destination_ip: ['{{ ruleset.destination_ip }}']
        action: '{{ ruleset.action }}'
        disabled: '{{ ruleset.disabled }}'
        location: '{{ ruleset.location }}'
        log_end: '{{ ruleset.log_end }}'
        tag_name: '{{ ruleset.tag_name }}'
        vsys: '{{ ruleset.vsys }}'
        state: '{{ ruleset.state }}'
        commit: '{{ ruleset.commit }}'
        with_dict:
          - "{{ ruleset }}"
...
```

The output I was expecting from ansible is to loop through and produce output like this for each block of data:

```
  panos_security_rule:
    ip_address: '192.168.1.1'
    username: 'test'
    password: 'test'
    rule_name: 'Ansible test 1'
    description: 'An Ansible test rule'
    source_zone: ['trust']
    destination_zone: ['untrust']
    source_ip: ['1.2.3.4']
    source_user: ['any']
    destination_ip: ['any']
    action: 'allow'
    disabled: 'False'
    location: 'top'
    log_end: 'true'
    tag_name: 'superimportant'
    vsys: 'vsys1'
    state: 'present'
    commit: 'True'
```

The error I am getting is

```
TASK [include variables] *****************************************************************************************************
fatal: [localhost]: FAILED! => {"msg": "Syntax Error while loading YAML.\n  mapping values are not allowed here\n\nThe error appears to have been in '/root/ansible/vars/vars.yml': line 3, column 16, but may\nbe elsewhere in the file depending on the exact syntax problem.\n\nThe offending line appears to be:\n\n  rule_name: testrule1\n    description: Test Rule number 1\n               ^ here\n"}
        to retry, use: --limit @/root/ansible/panos_dynamic.retry
```

I have been reading the docs and posts and I have tried reformatting the dictionary file and using with_items, with_dict, enclosing in "{{ }}", and without brackets and I just seem to be completely stuck.

Am I missing something simple here?

Comment: The errror relates to `vars.yml`, but you have not mentioned that file in your question. Could you clarify if this is the same as `vars_dict.yml`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are a few tweaks which may solve your question.

Firstly, use a list instead of a dict to define the roles. Both work but a list is slightly cleaner code.

Second the `with_dict` notation needs to be indented to the same level as the task and not the task parameters.

Finally, your question uses `ruleset` as the loop variable. By default this would be `item` and it needs to be something different to the list/dict variable being iterated.

Example:
  vars_dict.yml

```
---
ruleset:
  - rule_name: testrule1
    description: Test Rule number 1
    source_zone: trust
    destination_zone: untrust
    source_ip: 1.2.3.4
    source_user: any
    destination_ip: 4.5.6.7
    action: allow
    disabled: FALSE
    location: top
    log_end: TRUE
    tag_name: superimportant
    vsys: vsys1
    state: present
    commit: TRUE

  - rule_name: testrule2
    description: Test Rule number 2
    source_zone: trust
    destination_zone: untrust
    source_ip: 1.2.3.5
    source_user: any
    destination_ip: 4.5.6.8
    action: allow
    disabled: FALSE
    location: bottom
    log_end: TRUE
    tag_name: superimportant
    vsys: vsys1
    state: present
    commit: TRUE
```

Playbook:
    ---
    - hosts: localhost
      connection: local

```
  roles:
    - role: PaloAltoNetworks.paloaltonetworks

  tasks:
    - name: include variables
      include_vars:
        dir: vars

    - name: Add superimportant rules to the firewall
      panos_security_rule:
        ip_address: '{{ fw_ip_address }}'
        username: '{{ fw_username }}'
        password: '{{ fw_password }}'
        rule_name: '{{ item.rule_name }}'
        description: '{{ item.description }}'
        source_zone: ['{{ item.source_zone }}']
        destination_zone: ['{{ item.destination_zone }}']
        source_ip: ['{{ item.source_ip }}']
        source_user: ['{{ item.source_user }}']
        destination_ip: ['{{ item.destination_ip }}']
        action: '{{ item.action }}'
        disabled: '{{ item.disabled }}'
        location: '{{ item.location }}'
        log_end: '{{ item.log_end }}'
        tag_name: '{{ item.tag_name }}'
        vsys: '{{ item.vsys }}'
        state: '{{ item.state }}'
        commit: '{{ item.commit }}'
      with_items:
        - "{{ ruleset }}"
```

Comment: I updated the files but I am still getting an error, unfortunately.

Comment: I updated the files but I was still getting an error but your earlier comment regarding vars.yml and yars_dict.yml got me thinking.  Turns out that I had both files (formatted differently) in the directory which was clobbering my output!  I removed the bad one and it is working now!  Thanks so much for your help!  I am brand new to yaml and I even used a yaml aware editor to avoid spacing issues (PyCharm) but that still nailed me!  Do you have any suggestions to keep me out of formatting trouble in the future?